# How to understand nested generators in python?

Tags: python, generator

I have this code:

```
def flat_on_level1(it, d=-1, level=None):
    """

    >>> list(flat_on_level1([[[['a']]]], level=3))
    [['a']]

    """
    if d==-1:
        return list(flat_on_level1(it, d=d+1, level=level))

    if d==level:
        return (i  for i in [it])

    for x in it:
        yield from flat_on_level1(x, d=d+1, level=level)
```

I would expect the same as here:

```
def flat_on_level(it, d=-1, level=None):
    """
    >>> list(flat_on_level([[[['a']]]], level=3))
    [['a']]

    """
    if d == -1:
        return list(flatt_on_level(it, d=d + 1, level=level))

    if d == level:
        return (i for i in [it])

    res = []
    for x in it:
        res.extend( flat_on_level(x, d=d+1, level=level))
    return res
```

I get an empty list back. What is going on here?

Thanks looking forward like a generator. I don't get it. I have to write some more text here, but I think, the question is clear enough by the example.

Comment: Neither version of the code make much sense to me. You seldom want to mix `return` statements with `yield` statements in the same function, since `return` doesn't work the normal way in a generator.

Comment: what is `x` in that last line and how is the function supposed to work? It's pretty nonsensical as it is now

Comment: Your second function has a call to `flatt_on_level()` in it which is clearly a typo.

Comment: It's all about boxing and biting in the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yield only returns one value at a time. You need to call yield as many times as the length of your list

Answer (score 1):

Read this

https://pythontips.com/2013/09/29/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/

Basically you would need to iterated through the second version to get the same effect as calling the first (which has a generator).

Answer (score 0):

So ok, without the help of the great hint's I got to this. It seems to be a nice generator. My question was more about the tactics reformulating the function, that one can yield to one flat list, than what I did wrong in concrete.

```
def flat_on_level(it, d=-1, level=None):
    """

    >>> list(flat_on_level([[[['a']]]], level=3))
    ['a']

    """
    if isinstance(it, dict):
        y = it.values()
    else:
        y = it
    if not isinstance(y, collections.Iterable):
        yield y
    else:
        for x in y:
            if d == level:
                yield x
            else:
                yield from flat_on_level(x, d=d + 1, level=level)
```